Teams webinar registration APi
Any one can help he on teams webinar registration APi with json body and what are the permissions need for this
I want to register attendee in Microsoft Team Webinar by using my system, for this I need an API.
Does Graph API support to add an attendee for

Please refer this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingregistration-post-registrants?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
